# zero exterior power in Fredholm determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

The Fredholm determinant of operator $I+A$ with $A$ is trace-class, is defined by:

$det(I+A)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}Tr(\Lambda^{k}(A))$

Where $\Lambda^{k}(A)$ is defined by $\Lambda^{k}(A)v_{1}\wedge...\wedge v_{k}=Av_{1}\wedge...\wedge Av_{k}$.

The thing I don't understand is the definition of $\Lambda^{0}(A)$, how is it defined? Is it just $I$? But for infinite dimension $Tr(I)=\infty$, so what is $Tr(\Lambda^{0}(A))$?

Comment: From the context, my best guess is that $\Lambda^0(A) = 1$, which is to say that it is the identity over a **one-dimensional** space and so has trace $1$.